# Headless Chromium renders non-latin characters in Type 3 font

Tags: html, pdf, fonts, chromium, html-to-pdf

When I use the headless Chromium `--print-to-pdf` on a Debian Docker container to print a web page containing non-Latin characters into PDF, the printed PDF contains Type 3 font. I want to get rid of this font type since it's obsolete and may not be PDF/A compliant.

The HTML file `non-latin.html` content:

```html
<html>
<body>
中文内容
</body>
</html>
```

Run headless Chromium on Debian to print HTML to PDF

```
chrome --headless --disable-gpu --no-sandbox --print-to-pdf non-latin.html
```

The printed `output.pdf` displayed the non-Latin characters. However, the Acrobat shows the PDF file contains 4 Type 3 fonts. I want to render these characters in other TrueType fonts like NotoSans.

> I already installed the `fonts-noto` in the Docker container.

[image]